# How to make a folder in opt and paste something?

Tags: command-line, directory, system

I am using Ubuntu 17.10, I want to make a folder in **opt** folder/directory and paste something but when I open the **opt** folder and right click on it the new folder option is unhighlighted and also the paste option I tried to make the folder in opt folder using terminal by **mkdir** command but it shows Permission denied.

Plz tell me how to do it?

Comment: Your user account does not have permission to write to the `/opt` directory.  Could you [edit] your question and explain why you want to put something in there?  I'd rather understand what you are doing before giving you an answer that could potentially be a bit dangerous.

Comment: `sudo chmod +w /opt` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you require root permission.
In case you have the root password, in terminal do the following:

```
cd  /opt
sudo mkdir name-of-the-folder
cd name-of-the-folder
sudo cp path-of-file-to-be-copied/file-to-be-copied .
```

Don't forget the Dot (.) at the end of the last command.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71732/discussion-on-answer-by-jay-how-to-make-a-folder-in-opt-and-paste-something).